# How to center or scale zoomButton image?

Tags: android, layout, button

I have problem with round zoom button. Its image does not stretch and does not center in button area but it is always at left border. Look at the picture.
I would like to stretch zoom button image or at least to have buttons centered.
Is it possible?
Both buttons lay on RelativeLayout.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 android:gravity="center"
```

property on your button.